# How to print list of users and groups on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, command

How to print list of users and groups on FreeBSD?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

users and groups stored in /etc/group and /etc/passwd. To print:

```
awk -F":" '{print $1}' /etc/passwd
awk -F":" '{print $1}' /etc/group
```

for more details

```
awk -F":" '{print $0 $1 $2}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: On FreeBSD you get some comment lines in the beginning. Add  | grep -v "^#" to delete those from output.